# How make a pull request to cloned project from private personal repo

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-pull

There was a task assigned to me for interview with below delivery instructions:
Clone this repository in a new GitHub repository in private mode and share with mentioned ID: whatever-id in private mode on github.com, make sure you do not erase my commits and then create a pull request (code review)

I've cloned it to my newly created private repo & worked on it on the same branch. made many commits.

now I've finished the task. my only issue is how to make pull request in this situation.

When I go to project repo and pull request section of project I click to make new pull request But it doesn't shows other peoples branches or repos to make a merge to the one I'm looking for.

even when I click compare across forks. I can't see other peoples projects. is it related that my project is in private repo ? if so why the task assgined ask me this...

So If you know how to make it work or have any information I'll be thankful.

Comment: I assume it means creating a PR in the repo you created, not in the parent repo (but I may be wrong).

Comment: @wRAR Considering the task was small with few features involved, I made all changes in one branch. Should I have created a separate branch, made changes, and then submitted a pull request from that branch to the development branch? Can I still do the pull request despite making changes in one branch?

Comment: You should always have two branches, the one with your changes and the one you based it on (maybe it's the one you called "the development branch" but we don't know your repo layout and the workflows.